# Java: NoClassDefFoundError when adding package statement

Tags: java

The java source code is as below:

```
package test;

public class DotMain {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String s1 = "abcdex";
        String s2 = "ac";
        boolean[] r1 = new boolean[26];
        for (char c : s1.toCharArray())
            r1[c - 'a'] = true;
        boolean contained = true;
        for (char c : s2.toCharArray()) {
            if (!r1[c - 'a']) {
                contained = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(contained);
        System.out.println(s1 + s2);
    }
}
```

If there is no "package test;" the corresponding class file will behave correct. But when I add "package test;" the exception as stated in the title occured. Is there something wrong?

Comment: have you cross checked your class exists in package test..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you're not building it properly or not running it properly.

Build it like this (filling in the path information appropriately):

```
javac -d . path/to/DotMain.java
```

Run it like this:

```
java test.DotMain
```

(You can change the output directory specified by `-d` of course, at which point you should either add that directory to the classpath or change to that directory before running.)

Comment: I compile the source code like your suggestion "javac -d . d:\eclipsews\DotMain.java" and run it like "java test.DotMain" and it succeeded. Thanks! But why does it fail by compiling like "javac DotMain.java"?

Comment: @wix: You need the .class files to be in a directory structure mirroring your package structure. You can do that by putting the *source code* in the same structure - which you should certainly do for any significant work - or just use the `-d` option.